# How to change items in navigation menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu on top of my page. Lets say the menu has 2 items:

```
 Home | Contact.
```

Now depending on the login of user the menu items will change. Lets say if admin login's than there will be an extra item in the navigation menu and the menu will become:

```
Home  |  Contact  |  Admin
```

But how am i going to do it?

Thought of several ways like:

1. make separate menus and with php i will make the menu visible to user, which will be needed- and the other one hidden/invisible.
2. Using php, add the items -that are needed.

How can i do it really?

Comment: Either. This is not a question well suited to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. use javascript template engine (like underscore.template )**

templateObj + templateString = renderedLayout

**2. javascript Array.join('|')**

use javascript array for prepare to append u menu

```js
var renderMenu = function(menu){
  menu = menu || [
    '<a href="/lalala" >Home</a>',
    '<a href="/lololo" >Contact</a>'
  ];

  menu = menu.join(' | ');
  document.getElementById('menu_holder').innerHTML= menu;

};

//first run
renderMenu();


///button handlers
var withoutUser = function() {
  renderMenu();
};

var user = function() {
  var menu = [
    '<a href="/lalala" >Home</a>',
    '<a href="/lololo" >Contact</a>',
    '<a href="/profile">Admin</a>'
  ];
  renderMenu(menu);
};
```

```html
<button onclick="user()">render with user</button>
<button onclick="withoutUser()">render withOUT user</button>
<div id="menu_holder"></div>
```

**3. use CSS**

```css
.menu-item {
  list-style:none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item:before {
  content: '|';
}
.menu-item:first-child:before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<li class="menu-item">
  <a class="menu-link"href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
  <a class="menu-link"href="#">Contacts</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
  <a class="menu-link"href="#">Admin</a>
</li>
```

luke.

Comment: whao..didnt even know these things.Sorry, a  newbie here for web designing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use database, if you have more than two user roles. Assign required roles to each menu item.
2. Use PHP for adding it, if there's only one 'Admin' item.